# Set controls inside a control inside same row of TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I create a TableLayoutPanel where I want to add two buttons one next to other so I try:

First I create panel as:

```
  var pnlButtons = new TableLayoutPanel
            {
                Name = "pnlButtons",
                AutoSize = true,
                AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink,
                Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
                RowCount = 1,
                TabIndex = 1
            };

            pnlButtons.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            pnlButtons.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle());
            pnlButtons.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());

            pnlButtons.HandleCreated += new EventHandler(pnlButtons_Created);
            this.Controls.Add(pnlButtons);
```

Then I add buttons in event handler:

```
private void pnlButtons_Created (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var pnl = (TableLayoutPanel)sender;
            var btnSetAmount = new Button
            {
                Text = "Set Amounts",
                Name = "btnSetAmount",
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right,
                TabIndex = 0,
                UseVisualStyleBackColor = true

            };
            pnl.Controls.Add(btnSetAmount);

            var btnCancel = new Button
            {
                Text = "Cancel",
                Name = "btnCancel",
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left,
                TabIndex = 1,
                UseVisualStyleBackColor = true
            };
            pnl.Controls.Add(btnCancel);

        }
```

But when I run it I see something like this:

[image]

It is in a different row. How can I do in order to set in the same row? Regards

Update: after comments above now it show it like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TableLayoutPanel has an override on the Controls collection that allows you to specify the column and row:

```
pnl.Controls.Add(btnSetAmount, 0, 0);
pnl.Controls.Add(btnCancel, 1, 0);
```

Comment: It works. But now if I want to get 100% of width of that Panel and create buttons 50% and 50% depending of panel width, how can I achieve that?

Comment: @Leon Try setting your columns to 50% and then Dock Fill your buttons instead of Anchoring them.